# jQuery selector for select box options?

Tags: jquery

I have a few multiple select boxes.

In each box, there are a few options you can click on, as well as a category "ALL".

I want to make it that when you select ALL, the rest of the options in that box become disabled. I need to have a way to select the rest of the options in the box and I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: category All - you mean optgroup??

Comment: Or do you mean if the user selects 'ALL' that all other options are de-selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want (working example: http://jsfiddle.net/k7X6T/):

```
$("#s").change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == "all")
        $this.children("option").not("#all").prop("disabled", true);
    else
        $this.children("option").prop("disabled", false);
});

<select id="s" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="all" id="all">All</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes, this is what I was asking for, but I realized later that this really isn't what I want. The way this works, it makes the other options be disabled and there is no way of ever enabling them again. What I really wanted was something that would disallow someone to chose other options once they already chose ALL (because ALL means "every option")

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
   $("#Select1 option").attr('disabled', true);
   $("#Select1 #AllOption").attr('disabled', false);

    <select id="Select1">
            <option id="AllOption">ALL</option>
            <option>Red</option>
            <option>Green</option>
            <option>Blue</option>
    </select>
```

First disable all the options, then enable the one you want enabled.  I gave it an ID to make it easier.